# Win events replace by boost signals (threadsafe)

Tags: c++, boost

I want to change win32 events with something portable so I decided to use boost.signals2.

Right now I have something like:

```
ret = WaitForMultipleObjets
{
    switch(ret)
    {
        case Timeout: something; break;
        case Event1: something; break;
        case Event2: something; break;
    }
}
```

and I think that the good idea is to replace this with something like that:

```
for(;;)
{
    Execute code from timeout, if event occurs interrupt and execute
    code which is responsible for event handling
}
```

but I don't know how can I implement this. Maybe I can join lambda slot with signal and cause interruption in timeout code ( usual routine ).

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The "direct" translation of Win32 Events would be `std::condition_variable` or `boost::condition_variable` though.

Because `signals2` does not imply any kind of synchonization and you need it if you the replacement to get the same semantics.

That said, I usually turn to Boost Asio for event-driven code, or use a (message) queue for IPC if it's really more like passing messages between threads.

Here's the Boost Asio idea:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c617b4a8fdc8251)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
namespace as = boost::asio;

// basically used as a callback queue for the simple reason we don't do
// asynchronous IO (yet)
as::io_service shared_queue; 

void worker(int id) {
    while (!shared_queue.stopped()) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 1000));

        shared_queue.post([id] {
                std::cout << "event from thread #" << id << " handled on " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
            });
    }
}

int main() {
    thread_group threads;

    threads.create_thread(bind(worker, 1)); // arbitrary number of sources for events
    threads.create_thread(bind(worker, 2));
    threads.create_thread(bind(worker, 3));

    {
        as::io_service::work keep_running(shared_queue);
        threads.create_thread([] { shared_queue.run(); });

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(4));
    } // after 4 seconds, `keep_running` is destructed, making `run()` exit when idle

    shared_queue.stop();

    threads.join_all();
}
```

Typical output:

```
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #3 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #3 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #3 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #3 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #1 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #3 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #3 handled on 7f8478a06700
event from thread #2 handled on 7f8478a06700
```

Comment: Added the Boost Asio approach to event queueing. Note you can add arbitrary numbers of threads calling `run()` on the `shared_queue` (as long as you take all the usual precautions w.r.t. accessing shared data). Note that `boost::asio::io_service` _itself_ is thread safe

Answer (score 1):

I try to port https://github.com/NeoSmart/PEvents on boost but if you wait for the same event in multiple places it can cause deadlock on scoped lock (which is necessary when you wait for cond var in boost).

So this time i try something like this:

```
for(;;)
{
    auto c = signal.connect([]()
    {
        ThreadHandle->interrupt();
        //code for handling event1
    });

    try
    {
        //code for timeout
    }
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted&)
    {
        //thread interrupted by signal listener
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

when signal is 'catched' I interrupt main flow (timeout) and do stuff which should be done if event occurs.

Comment: this is a code smell in my book; you're using threads to idle (that's not gonna scale) and also using exceptions for flow control

Comment: Yes, this is answer, but I also expect opinions about my idea. Could you tell me book's tittle ? I read C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading, but I don't use this book to write this code. But let's back to main problem, in your opinior this is a good solution ?

Comment: Re. [In my book](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/in+my+book.html) :) I've added one of the approaches to my answer. The other ones depend (much) too heavily on how things are used in the actual code base.

Comment: I'd actually ask about the specific deadlock ifyou can't figure it out. Boost has the free function variation of `lock` that takes multiple locks. You can use this to await multiple locks without deadlock.

Comment: I am not sure if reursive mutex can be user in ondition variable

boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(event->Mutex);
result = event->CVariable.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(milliseconds));

this is example with 'normal' mutex

Comment: I've never mentioned recursive mutexes. Free function `lock` will work with any lockables: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions